# Markov chains: If $P$ is irreducible and $\pi$ any stationary distribution, then $\pi_i = \frac{1}{m_i}$.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I am trying to understand a proof of the following claim:

If $P$ is irreducible and $\pi$ any stationary distribution, then $\pi_i = \frac{1}{m_i}$, where $m_i$ is the mean return time to state $i$.

---

Here's the proof:

Suppose $\pi$ is stationary for $P$, and let $X$ be a Markov chain with initial distribution $\pi$ and transition matrix $P$. Let $V_i(n)$ be the number of visits to state $i$ before time $n$. Then, by stationarity, $\mathbb{P}(X_n=i) = \pi_i$ for all $n$, and
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}[V_i(n)]}{n} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}[1\{X_r=i\}]
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{P}(X_r=i)
= \pi_i
\tag{$1$} \label{ref1}
$$
From the ergodic theorem, for any $\epsilon$,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{V_i(n)}{n} - \frac{1}{m_i} \right| > \epsilon\right) < \epsilon \tag{$2$} \label{ref2}
$$
for large enough $n$ (since almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability).

But since $\frac{V_i(n)}{n}$ is bounded between $0$ and $1$, it follows from \eqref{ref2} that
$$
\boxed{\frac{\mathbb{E}[V_i(n)]}{n} \to \frac{1}{m_i} \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty}
$$
Comparing to \eqref{ref1}, we obtain $\pi_i = \frac{1}{m_i}$.

---

Why does the boxed statement follow from \eqref{ref2}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read (2) as

$$\mathbb{P}\left(-\epsilon   \le \frac{V_i(n)}{n}-\frac{1}{m_i} \le \epsilon\right ) > 1- \epsilon$$

and this  means with probability $1-\epsilon<1$ the absolute difference is less than $\epsilon$ and with the other probability $\epsilon$ the absolute difference is less than $1$ (since $\frac{V_i}{n}$ is bounded between $0$ and $1$), so  there is a probability at least $1−ϵ$ that $\frac{V_i(n)}{n}-\frac{1}{m_i}$ is between $−ϵ$ and $+ϵ$; otherwise it is between $−1$ and $+1$. So its expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{V_i(n)}{n}-\frac{1}{m_i}\right]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[V_i(n)]}{n}-\frac{1}{m_i}$ is bounded below by $(1−ϵ)×(−ϵ)+ϵ×(−1)>−2ϵ$ and bounded above by $(1−ϵ)×(+ϵ)+ϵ×(+1)<+2ϵ$, i.e.

$$-2\epsilon < \frac{\mathbb{E}[V_i(n)]}{n}-\frac{1}{m_i} < 2\epsilon$$ for large enough $n$ (which depends on $\epsilon$).  You can then take $\epsilon$ as small as you like to conclude $$\frac{\mathbb{E}[V_i(n)]}{n} \to \frac{1}{m_i} \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty.$$

Comment: Thanks. Why is the absolute difference is less than one, though?

Comment: I'm not really sure how you got the second inequality. How do you go from probability to expectation?

Comment: $\frac{V_i(n)}{n}$ is between $0$ and $1$ and $\frac{1}{m_i}$ is between $0$ and $1$ so their absolute difference is between $0$ and $1$

Comment: There is a probability at least $1-\epsilon$ that $\frac{V_i(n)}{n}-\frac{1}{m_i}$ is between $-\epsilon$ and $+\epsilon$; otherwise it is between $-1$ and $+1$.  So its expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{V_i(n)}{n}-\frac{1}{m_i}\right]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[V_i(n)]}{n}-\frac{1}{m_i}$ is bounded below by $(1-\epsilon)\times(-\epsilon)+\epsilon\times (-1) > -2\epsilon$  and bounded above by $(1-\epsilon)\times(+\epsilon)+\epsilon\times (+1) <+2\epsilon$

Comment: Ah thank you, that makes more sense. Perhaps you could add this to the answer to make it clearer?